# St_OffSetCurve with self-crossing lines

Tags: postgresql, routing, postgis-2.0, parallel-lines

I have about 50,000 linestrings in PostGIS. They represent routes along roads. But I want them to be (roughly) pavements (aka sidewalks) instead. So I need to move all the lines 3 metres to the left of the direction they are travelling.

I found this function:

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html

And tried to implement it, however some of my lines are self crossing, and thus it doesn't work. I think that this is reason anyway. An error I get it:

"ERROR:  GEOSOffsetCurve: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get offset of single-vertex line"

I presume that this is becase there are some straight lines aswell as curves. So I need to cope with this.

Also, when I try to store these, sometimes it says that the result of st_offsetcurve has created a multi-string - though I'm not sure why?

Does anyone know of how I could do this please?

Thanks

James

Comment: Does st_offsetcurve() really fail when the given line is self-crossing? I'm not disagreeing with you, just surprised because, while self-crossing boundaries are erroneous, self-crossing routes aren't necessarily wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining very well. One of the errors I get when I try to use st_offsetcurve is:  'ERROR:  GEOSOffsetCurve: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get offset of single-vertex line'. I've edited my question above to add more detail.

Answer (score 2):

A single-vertex line is an invalid geometry. It is essentially a point geometry. A line-offset cannot be determined for a line with only one vertex.

Try eliminate invalid geometries with a filter on [`ST_IsValid`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html):

```
SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(t.geom, 3)
FROM the_table AS t
WHERE ST_IsValid(t.geom);
```